# Fetch data with id from url params on ssr

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to get data from fetch but one argument in fetch is a parameter from the actual URL.
I am using Nextjs.

Here is my code:

```
const Room = () => {
  let fetchData;
  let roomId;

  const getID = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const { id } = router.query;
    roomId = id;
    console.log("ID + " + roomId);
  };

  const getDataNames = () => {
    try {
      fetch("http://localhost:1337/rooms?_id=" + roomId)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => (fetchData = data));
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  };

  getID();
  getDataNames();

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{roomId}</p>
      <p>{fetchData}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

first i call `getID()` which gaves me undefined and then is called `getDataNames()` but in url is undefined param because roomId is undefined.

And I don't know how to fix it. But what I don't understand too is why are functions called twice.
[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lx6FL.png)

Comment: why do not you wrap fetch inside the first method and try to see if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In React is discouraged calling functions inside component body. Much better using an hook like `useEffect`. So if you want to call `getID()` and `getDataNames()` one time at component loading you could write:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getID();
  getDataNames();
}, []);
```

In this way you are sure that functions will be called one time.

Not only but I would change your code like this:

```
const Room = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  
  useEffect(() => {
     if (router.asPath !== router.route) {
        getDataNames();
     }
  }, [router]);
  
  const getDataNames = () => {
    try {
      fetch("http://localhost:1337/rooms?_id=" + router.query.id)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => (fetchData = data));
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
   }
  };
  ...
```

In this way you don't need `getID()` function.

Comment: Thanks its really a better approach but i am still getting errror in console `.js:14 GET http://localhost:1337/rooms?_id=undefined 500 (Internal Server Error)` that id is still undefined. ( I tried your entire code)

Comment: @Michaelo so `router` value comes async. No problem, you could try to put `router` in useEffect param list. I will update my answer.